# Booking system using google calendar API, when retrieving existing events from the calendar the code breaks. Can someone help me with this?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm creating a Python-based app with a booking system that will allow users to create an event on a specific google calendar, using google calendar API.

Code worked well when creating events that don't overlap on other.

However I want to check that no event overlap before creating an event, so I added code to check for overlapping events. If events overlap, I want to redirect the user to the booking form again (without creating an event).

I debugged using print statements and found that the code stops working at this part of my code:

```
events_result = (
        service.events()
        .list(
            calendarId=DENTIST_CALENDAR_ID,
            timeMin=new_details['appointment_datetime'].isoformat(),
            timeMax=(new_details['appointment_datetime'] + datetime.timedelta(hours=2)).isoformat(),
            singleEvents=True,
            orderBy='startTime',
        )
        .execute()
    )
```

And the error that it gives me is this:

```
[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request'}]
```

I've already verified that the time format is consistent through out the entire code. Does anyone know what could be happening ?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.